# Count Outlook Emails Sent to Self via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

How does one get the count of Outlook emails sent to self via the Microsoft Graph API Get request?

Among other things, here's what I've tried:

- Combining $search and $filter (not supported):
  `f"{BASE_URL}/users/{email}/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq '{email}'&$search=\\"cc:{email}\\""`
- Combining $search and $count (not supported): `f"{BASE_URL}/users/{email}/messages?$search=\\"cc:{email}\\"&$count=true"`
- Combining $filter with complex collections (not supported):
  `f"{BASE_URL}/users/{email}/messages?$filter=toRecipients/any(e:e/emailAddress/address eq '{email}')"`

I wish to avoid pulling the email details and wrangle upstream as the data contains thousands of emails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the pidtagmessagerecipientme extended property
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessagerecipientme-canonical-property which would give you email where your address is in the To or CC line and then also include a from filter to filter to just email that was sent from a particular address eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'Boolean 0x0059' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Boolean) eq true) and from/emailAddress/address eq 'address@dom.com'&$count=true
```

Comment: Thanks, Glen. It's seems to do the job.
However, I'm a little bit puzzled as to why the id=0x0057 when in the documentation you provided it's 0x0059. I've tried to check the JSON response but singleValueExtendedProperties is not included, even with $expand. I'm guessing that perhaps it may be due to our tenant settings.

Comment: Sorry it should have been 0x0059, 0x0057 is Message_to_me which only covers when your in the To Line where 59 covers both To and CC which it looks like what you where trying to do. There is also 58 where it covers if you just in the CC line

Comment: I see. Thank you, you've been great help.